# Get parent class of member in MouseEvent

Tags: c#, wpf, events, parent, member

I have a class with 3 members, only two of them relevant; one is a Polygon and the other a int[] of coordinates. I want to be aware of that Polygon corresponding coordinates but I am really stuck here.

By aware of the polygon coordinates I mean the abstract cubic coordinates I store in the class along that polygon and which I use to declare its Points.

The coordinates are X, Y and Z and I store them in an int[3] in the following class. And what I want to do is to be able to catch those cubic coordinates everytime the event is triggered.:

```
public class Tile
{
    public int[] coords;
    public Polygon hex;
    public List<object> content;
}
```

The List filler method:

```
        foreach (int[] i in ValidCoordinates)
        {
            int[] coords = i;

            double apotema = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(20, 2) - Math.Pow(20 / 2, 2));

            double auxX = x + (coords[0] * (20 * 3 / 2));
            double auxY = y + (coords[0] * apotema + (coords[1] * apotema * 2));

            Polygon poly = Hex.HexagonalPolygon(20, auxX, auxY);

            poly.Fill = Brushes.Blue;

            Hexagon.Tile tile = new Hexagon.Casilla();

            tile.coords = coords;
            tile.hex = poly;

            ListTiles.Add(tile);
        }
```

And I show the Polygon member on the List of Tiles like this...

```
foreach (Hexagon.Tile t in ListTiles)
{
    PolyCanvas.Children.Add(t.hex);
}
```

And then find the Polygon with a MouseEvent and change it's properties:

```
private void PolyCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource is Polygon)
    {
        Polygon poly = e.OriginalSource as Polygon;

        poly.Fill = Brushes.Red;
    }
}
```

A bit more of code... XMAL:

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="400"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Canvas Name="PolyCanvas" MouseDown="PolyCanvas_MouseDown" Height="700" Width="1200">
    </Canvas>
    <TextBox Name="txt" Grid.Row="1"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

I have thoroughly searched for an answer but I'm clueless.

Comment: Do you want to check if mouse pressed on polygon or on other?

Comment: On polygon, the one which I pressed.

Comment: Have you tried to get info from `sender`?

Comment: It shows the info of it's parent in the WPF, Windows.Controls.Canvas, in this case.

Comment: `var canvas = sender as Windows.Controls.Canvas;`
`if(canvas.Name == "polygon") {  //... }`

Comment: Can you get the name of the canvas? as mentioned in above comments

Comment: As I try to write Windows.Controls.Canvas it just says "the type or namespace Controls does not exist in the namespace Windows" which is weird because I have both the using and the assambly reference in the project and everything else controls-related works just fine.

Comment: Also have PresentationCore, PresentationFramework and so on in the references.

Comment: Which type of `PolyCanvas` is? Can you show more code?

Comment: Sure. Going to edit the question.

Comment: I got rid of `Windows.Controls` and the code you wrote throw "true" to the canvas.Name == "polygon" comparison.

Comment: I put answer, please try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach (int[] i in ValidCoordinates)
{
     int[] coords = i;

     double apotema = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(20, 2) - Math.Pow(20 / 2, 2));

     double auxX = x + (coords[0] * (20 * 3 / 2));
     double auxY = y + (coords[0] * apotema + (coords[1] * apotema * 2));

     Polygon poly = Hex.HexagonalPolygon(20, auxX, auxY);

     poly.Fill = Brushes.Blue;

     Hexagon.Tile tile = new Hexagon.Casilla();

     tile.coords = coords;
     tile.hex = poly;
     ListTiles.Add(tile);
}
...
//put values into tile and then set as tag
PolyCanvas.Tag = tile;
...
private void PolyCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{    
     var canvas = sender as System.Windows.Controls.Canvas;
     if (canvas.Name == "PolyCanvas")
     {
          if(canvas.Tag != null)
             var tiles = (Tile)canvas.Tag;
     }
}
```

Comment: I think you may missundertood me. I already could tell the coordinates X,Y of the polygon in relation with the canvas. The coordinates I was talking are the ones in the Class Tiles, which are cube coordinates (x,y,z) and have nothing to do with Point coordinates.
Sorry for being ambiguous, goin to edit the question now to make it clear. And thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: What do you want now?

Comment: I corrected the question, hope it's less confusing now.

Comment: Do you want to get tile object as well in mouse down event?

Comment: That's exactly what I need

Comment: What is `ListTile` in your foreach loop? do you want get `ListTile` or `Tile` object?

Comment: ListTile is a List<Tile> in which I store Tile ValidCoordinates() as int[3], hexagonal polygons as Polygons (the ones which shows up) and another List.

I need to access the Tile, not the ListTile, but it would be the same for me if could get the ListTile index, which I would use to access the Tile.

Comment: It just crash now:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in XAMLgon.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

  tile null XAMLgon.Hexagon.Tile

Comment: On which line. set tag correctly, but I will modify again

Comment: @AntonioManuelDomínguez I have update again, now it will not crash. If you set tag before mousedown then you can get it in mouse down event as `Tile`

Comment: Perfect! That did it! Thank you very much for your painstaking effort!